# Connect nodes from one part of bipartite graph if there is connection through second path

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite

I'm working on graph algorithm, which uses bipartite graph to represent relationship between packages and items in them.

I have a bipartite graph where one part contains all packages and other all items. Nodes are connected if package contains given item.

My task is to create a subpgrah with only nodes from one part - packages. Packages are connected if they contains the same item.
So I want to represent nodes from second part as edges connecting nodes from first part.

I'm working in networkx library. My current, straightforward, approach is very slow. Is there some existing graph algorithm that could solve my problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the size of the graph (edges & nodes)?

Comment: My first approach was iterating over all items and then joining all packages with this item to each other. But I've just found I can use projection algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection) and `nx.projected_graph(graph, parcels)` does the work.

Comment: Did using the projected graph got you a sufficient performance improvement?

Comment: Yes it did. Problem looks solved for me.

Comment: Cool! I'd add it as an answer, maybe with a small example.